# Use R to add strings to a destination field based on a match in other columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements, paste

I have a dataframe with with three populated columns (Submitted_Name, Status, Accepted_Name) and one empty column (Flag).

```
data.pre <- data.frame(
'Submitted_Name' = c('Aa achalensis Schltr. hort.','Aa argyrolepis Rchb.f.','Aa aurantiaca D.Trujillo pre Herbarium Practice','Aa brevis Schltr.','Aa calceata (Rchb.f.) Schltr.'),
'Status' = c('accepted','accepted','accepted','synonym','accepted'),
'Accepted_Name' = c('Aa achalensis var. alba Schltr.','Aa argyrolepis forma beta Rchb.f.','Aa aurantiaca_x D.Trujillo','Myrosmodes breve (Schltr.) Garay','Aa calceata (Rchb.f.) Schltr. comb.ined.'),
'Flag' = c('','','','','')
)
```

I would like to populate "Flag" with certain strings based on the presence of particular phrases in the Submitted_Name and Accepted_Name fields. If "hort." or "pre Herbarium Practice" appears in Submitted_Name, then I would like "submitted name is horticultural" or "submitted name is pre herbarium practice" to appear in "Flag". If the phrases "var." or "forma" or "_x" or "comb.ined" appear in the Accepted_Name field, then "variety", "form", "hybrid", or "accepted name is comb.ined" should be added to "Flag". If no triggering phrases, then "Flag" remains blank.

Summary:

from Submitted_Name

hort. = submitted name is horticultural

pre Herbarium Practice = submitted name is pre herbarium practice

from Accepted_Name

var. = variety

forma = form

_x = hybrid

comb.ined = accepted name is comb.ined

The desired result is:

```
data.post <- data.frame(
'Submitted_Name' = c('Aa achalensis Schltr. hort.','Aa argyrolepis Rchb.f.','Aa aurantiaca D.Trujillo pre Herbarium Practice','Aa brevis Schltr.','Aa calceata (Rchb.f.) Schltr.'),
'Status' = c('accepted','accepted','accepted','synonym','accepted'),
'Accepted_Name' = c('Aa achalensis var. alba Schltr.','Aa argyrolepis forma beta Rchb.f.','Aa aurantiaca_x D.Trujillo','Myrosmodes breve (Schltr.) Garay','Aa calceata (Rchb.f.) Schltr. comb.ined.'),
'Flag' = c('variety; submitted name is horticultural','form','hybrid; submitted name is pre herbarium practice','','accepted name is comb.ined.')
)
```

I can manage this with the laborious repetitive code below (and I'm fine with it remaining in this form) for instances where only a single value needs to be added to "Flag":

```
Master.Taxonomy$Flag <- ifelse(grepl("var.", Master.Taxonomy$Accepted_Name), "variety", Master.Taxonomy$Flag)
Master.Taxonomy$Flag <- ifelse(grepl("comb.ined.", Master.Taxonomy$Accepted_Name), "accepted name is comb.ined.", Master.Taxonomy$Flag)
Master.Taxonomy$Flag <- ifelse(grepl("_x", Master.Taxonomy$Accepted_Name), "hybrid", Master.Taxonomy$Flag)
Master.Taxonomy$Flag <- ifelse(grepl("pre Herbarium Practice", Master.Taxonomy$Submitted_Name), "submitted name is pre herbarium practice", Master.Taxonomy$Flag)
Master.Taxonomy$Flag <- ifelse(grepl("hort.", Master.Taxonomy$Submitted_Name), "submitted name is horticultural", Master.Taxonomy$Flag)
Master.Taxonomy$Flag <- ifelse(grepl("forma", Master.Taxonomy$Accepted_Name), "form", Master.Taxonomy$Flag)
```

however where two or more values are to be added the latter overwrites the former and I am left only with whatever was last added to "Flag".
I've tried messing with paste but have tied myself in knots.
NB that the order that the phrases appear in "Flag" is unimportant
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `case_when` and `str_detect` for this purpose. Instead of doing everything in the same column, you can create two different columns one for submitted flag another for the accepted flag and finally, you can combine both using `unite` to get the desired result.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.pre <- data.frame(
  'Submitted_Name' = c('Aa achalensis Schltr. hort.','Aa argyrolepis Rchb.f.','Aa aurantiaca D.Trujillo pre Herbarium Practice','Aa brevis Schltr.','Aa calceata (Rchb.f.) Schltr.'),
  'Status' = c('accepted','accepted','accepted','synonym','accepted'),
  'Accepted_Name' = c('Aa achalensis var. alba Schltr.','Aa argyrolepis forma beta Rchb.f.','Aa aurantiaca_x D.Trujillo','Myrosmodes breve (Schltr.) Garay','Aa calceata (Rchb.f.) Schltr. comb.ined.'),
  'Flag' = c('','','','','')
)

data.pre %>% 
  mutate(f1 = case_when(Submitted_Name %>% str_detect("hort") ~ "submitted name is horticultural",
                        Submitted_Name %>% str_detect("pre Herbarium Practice") ~ "submitted name is pre herbarium practice"),
         f2 = case_when(Accepted_Name %>% str_detect("var.") ~ "variety",
                        Accepted_Name %>% str_detect("comb.ined.") ~ "accepted name is comb.ined.",
                        Accepted_Name %>% str_detect("_x") ~ "hybrid",
                        Accepted_Name %>% str_detect("forma") ~ "form")) %>% 
  unite("Flag", c(f2,f1), na.rm = T, sep = "; ")
#>                                    Submitted_Name   Status
#> 1                     Aa achalensis Schltr. hort. accepted
#> 2                          Aa argyrolepis Rchb.f. accepted
#> 3 Aa aurantiaca D.Trujillo pre Herbarium Practice accepted
#> 4                               Aa brevis Schltr.  synonym
#> 5                   Aa calceata (Rchb.f.) Schltr. accepted
#>                              Accepted_Name
#> 1          Aa achalensis var. alba Schltr.
#> 2        Aa argyrolepis forma beta Rchb.f.
#> 3               Aa aurantiaca_x D.Trujillo
#> 4         Myrosmodes breve (Schltr.) Garay
#> 5 Aa calceata (Rchb.f.) Schltr. comb.ined.
#>                                               Flag
#> 1         variety; submitted name is horticultural
#> 2                                             form
#> 3 hybrid; submitted name is pre herbarium practice
#> 4                                                 
#> 5                      accepted name is comb.ined.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>